# What Linux command will tell me where a window is in terms of the Z-axis compared to other windows?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, x11, gnome

I'm looking to give some Linux command a window id as obtained by `xprop` or `wmctrl` or similar and have something tell me where in the "z-wards" stacking order that window currently is.

For example, if window C is visually behind window B (as in B is clipping C, if they overlap each other), and window A is in front of both them, some command would tell me something like `0` for window A, `1` for B, and `2` for C.  Perhaps the "front" number is bigger than the "back" number; that's unimportant to me.

Comment: What's your operating system and window manager?

Comment: No Linux command (Linux is just the kernel), are you looking for an X11 command. for the Gnu/Linux system? And which distro?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is not a window *property* but a side-effect of the way X displays windows.  Looking for details on `XRaiseWindow` leads to `XRestackWindows` and seeing that it reorders a list of the windows (which given that it changes the order in which the X server *displays* them, controls the apparent stacking order).

The [`xwininfo`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/irix/man1/X11/xwininfo.1.html) command can return a list of child-windows for any window, and a *tree* of windows.  That's presented in the same order (it uses [`XQueryTree`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XQueryTree.3.html), whose description says that it lists the children in current stacking order), you could (with some effort) make a script that analyzed that and relate it to the windows that you care about (not all windows are interesting).

Window-ids aren't that useful, but you can use those as a parameter to `xprop` and find the window-titles that correspond.  Not all windows have titles, and there are some quirks to account for along the way.

(The solution is neither bash- or linux-specific, and predates both of those).

Someone alluded to [*EWMH*](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)'s [*`_NET_CLIENT_LIST`*](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm45390969666944):

> **`_NET_CLIENT_LIST, WINDOW[]/32`**
> **`_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING, WINDOW[]/32`**
>
> These arrays contain all X Windows managed by the Window Manager. **`_NET_CLIENT_LIST`** has initial mapping order, starting with the oldest window. **`_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING`** has bottom-to-top stacking order. These properties SHOULD be set and updated by the Window Manager.

In a quick check, that illustrates the quirks to explore.

```
$ xprop -root
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x400023
_NET_CLIENT_LIST(WINDOW): window id # 0x400023, 0xc00018, 0xa0000a
_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id # 0xa0000a, 0xc00018, 0x400023, 0xc00018
_NET_SUPPORTED(ATOM) = _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, _NET_CLIENT_LIST, _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING, _NET_CLOSE_WINDOW, _NET_SUPPORTED, _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS, _NET_WM_NAME, _NET_WM_STATE, _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MODAL, _NET_WM_STATE_SHADED, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_COMBO, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DND, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DROPDOWN_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_SPLASH, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLBAR, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLTIP, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_UTILITY
_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK(WINDOW): window id # 0x800001
_XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "base", "empty", "empty", "", ""
_NATIVE_SCREEN_ORIGIN(INTEGER) = 0, 22
```

I have 3 windows, and the stacking lists one twice.  Also, *which* window is the parent of the visible clients can differ according to the window manager in use.

And of course, there are still window managers which don't follow *EWMH*.  Even within *EWMH*, you have to appreciate that [**"SHOULD"**](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt).  It doesn't guarantee success.

For comparison, of course:

```
$ xwininfo -root -children

xwininfo: Window id: 0x111 (the root window) (has no name)

  Root window id: 0x111 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
     7 children:
     0x80000a (has no name): ()  806x853+0+1  +0+1
     0x40007d (has no name): ()  225x401+183+45  +183+45
     0x40007c (has no name): ()  295x464+101+45  +101+45
     0x800010 (has no name): ()  164x186+1113+5  +1113+5
     0x80000d (has no name): ()  246x159+950+0  +950+0
     0x800001 (has no name): ()  1x1+0+0  +0+0
     0x600001 (has no name): ()  1x1+0+0  +0+0
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638885/linux-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-visible-windows) works, and I believe will work with any X based distro:

```
xprop -root | grep '_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW)'
```

The result on my system is:

```
_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id # 0x3800003, 0x380000b, 0x58000fa, 0x5800006, 0x4a00d48
```

The IDs are ordered from left to right by z-order.  From there it's trivial to use the information as one desires.

`xprop` may need to be installed.

Comment: Notice the version without grep: `xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING`

Comment: Huh, cool, thanks.

Comment: I considered that, but no, it doesn't work for ***all*** window managers.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer to any question that's going to cover every single edge case.  I think the above is going to work 90%+ of the time.